# masterpage module override

Tags: .net, asp.net, master-pages, httpmodule

I have a masterpage which is set via a HTTPModule on PreInit().  HAPPY TIME!  Problem is I need to override the masterpagefile value on a few pages due to a layout issue. Anyone know the best way?

I tried adding a Page_Preinit on my page, but it is executed before the PreInit() in my module, so it ends up being reset there.  I'm thinking maybe I should update a context variable in my page (something like masterSetAtPage which I might branch off of in my module).. any thoughts on that?

I'm working in VB.Net, but a C# example would be fine also.

Comment: Can you update the PreInit code to specify the master page you need, or does the master page need to update based on the content being loaded?

Comment: Can you be more descriptive about what you want to do? The big obstacle is usually getting PreInit to successfully set the Masterpage, why not just not set it, or set it to another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably your current code looks a little like the code described here...

http://www.odetocode.com/articles/450.aspx

If so, then you can change your code that hooks up the PreInit to look something like this...

```
if (page != null && String.IsNullOrEmpty(page.MasterPageFile))
{
    page.MasterPageFile = "~/Master1.master";
}
```

and then any page that uses it's own page directive to set a masterpagefile will avoid being hooked up to the "default" master page.

If you need to do this programatically, then this code...

```
protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPreInit(e);
    this.MasterPageFile = "cheese.master";
}
```

... in your Page's code behind would do the trick. Obviously this code would only be added to pages where the special behaviour was needed.

Comment: That looks good, however, I actually need to programmatically set the master, so I can't set a static value in the page directive.

Comment: OK, so doing this...

protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPreInit(e);
    this.MasterPageFile = "cheese.master";
}

... in your page should work. I'm aware that this is pretty much what Mark suggested (above) - although he showed OnInit and not OnPreInit.

Comment: @Martin - yep, I pooched that one. ;) PreInit is the right place.